# Cannot sync pkgs and refresh pkg databases with 'pacman' under Archlinux

Tags: networking, arch-linux, pacman

On every Pacman command I get the following error
`error: failed to synchronize all database (invalid URL for server)`

How do I change the URL for the server? I was following this guide.
https://youtu.be/JRdYSGh-g3s

If run the command `sudo pacman -Sy` it outputs this.

[image: screenshot of pacman error messages]

This is the output of `grep -vP '^\s*#' /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist | grep .`:

[image: contents of mirrorlist]

(apologies for the pictures, I do not have a way to copy the text on the screen).

This error occurred after a successful installation. Additionally, I cannot seem to connect to the internet.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and tell us what you did. We are not going to watch a _37 minute_ youtube video! You need to tell us exactly what you did so we can understand the issue. More generally, Arch has some of the best documentation of the Linux world. Please use the official docs and not random youtube videos: https://wiki.archlinux.org/

Comment: @terdon I was trying to install a gui for my system. I am no longer on the live boot. Everything up to this point seems to be working fine, I guess I messed up somewhere in that part of setting up Pacman. Is it possible to fix it or do I need to start over with the docs instead?

Comment: Yes, please ***edit*** your question and add all this. Tell us what you were doing and at what point you got the error. I have no idea if it can be fixed because I still don't know when this happened. Was it part of the installation? Was it after successfully installing? What did you do to set up pacman? Just add al this to your question so we can understand. My first guess is that you have a bad URL in `/etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist`. Please also add the output of `grep -vP '^\s*#' /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist | grep .` to your question.

Comment: Alright I will edit my question, and yes it was after a successful installation.

Comment: You're getting `Could not resolve host` errors for all hosts, suggesting you may have missing or incorrect DNS settings. Does `grep nameserver /etc/resolv.conf` return anything? If it returns `nameserver 127.0.0.53`, run `resolvectl` and see what it says.

Comment: It returns nothing. @telcoM

Comment: Try configuring the system to use Google's public DNS resolver server: `echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" >>/etc/resolv.conf`. If you have a network configuration management system (e.g. NetworkManager) installed, this setting may not persist over a reboot; in that case, put the nameserver IP address wherever the configuration management system wants it.

Comment: In addition to the advice to add an actual DNS server, when you update Arch Linux or install a package, you always want to use `pacman -Syu` so that the repositories are syncronized. Not doing so can lead to repos that are unsynched with the system and can't be repaired.

Comment: Thanks, @sahil, that's much clearer! So, as others have said, your main issue is that you are not connected to the internet. Please follow the instructions here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Network_configuration. Or, even better, instead of following random youtube videos, just follow the Arch installation guide: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Installation_guide.